# log while hard close the console application C#

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a Console application Hosted in Task Scheduler. while my job is running, in some scenarios i will store some data in static lists and DataTables. and later i will log those data in single shot.

There is a scenario where technical team will stop the service manually before completion, in this case am missing to log the data that has captured in static list.

Is there any way we can log while the user stops the Console application manually.

Comment: What kind of *job*? You can perform job in transaction manner, so that you only produce valid results if complete operation is finished uninterrupted, otherwise you start from where you were interrupted (where transaction begins, e.g. you can split one job into multiple transactions). Otherwise answer would be No - you can't log when your application is shut down (or PC is turned off, etc.)

Comment: It picks some data from one service and transform that data and POST the data to different applications. Do transactions make application slower ?

Comment: How about [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)?